# unexpected behaviour of mysql query

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT i.id  AS item_id, 
       i.name, 
       i.project_id, 
       iv.id AS variation_id, 
       iv.price 
FROM   items AS i 
JOIN items_variations AS iv ON iv.id = (
    SELECT ivv.id FROM items_variations AS ivv 
    JOIN items_pictures AS ip2 
        ON ip2.variation_id = ivv.id 
        AND (( ip2.thumb = 1 AND ip2.details = 1 AND ip2.visible = 1 AND ip2.format = 3 ) 
            OR ( ip2.cover = 1 AND ip2.details = 1 AND ip2.visible = 1 AND ip2.format = 3 ) ) 
        WHERE  ivv.item_id = i.id AND ivv.status = 1 
        ORDER  BY ivv.price ASC 
        LIMIT  1) 
WHERE  i.id = 60
```

It returns the empty set. If I remove the field iv.price form the select clause, then one row is returned.
I am pretty astonished by this behaviour, do you have any clue on WHY this happens?

I am currently using mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: @fancyPants remove from the required fields.

Comment: sorry if I explained myself badly, I meant remove from the select clause

Comment: Try rebuilding indexes. If your indexes is corrupt, the inclusion of a column might pick a different (corrupt) index, and thus not return the right data. I have no idea whether MySQL can have corrupt indexes or how to rebuild them, but this one cause that would give that effect.

Comment: IDK if it's just I haven't used MySQL as much recently but your query looks un-necessarily complex for what your trying to achieve. Your two lines of AND/OR conditions in the JOIN can be reduced to `AND ((ip2.thumb = 1 OR ip2.cover = 1) AND ip2.details = 1 AND ip2.visible = 1 AND ip2.format = 3)` for example

Comment: @AeroX you're right, it's a query I wrote a long time ago and today I had to use it again after quite some time... and I found this unpleasant surpriese. I'm sure I can rewrite the query to avoid the problem, but I was curious on the reasonof it

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Is there some resource on the web that explains the reasoning behind your comment?